# Xml parser em Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Baixei um projeto pronto de rss Reader, ele vem titulo descrição e imagem.
Porem estou tentando editar o mesmo para o meu xml.

vejam os códigos:

```
//
//  FeedTableViewController.swift
//  RSSReader
//
//  Created by Training on 23/12/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Training. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, MWFeedParserDelegate, SideBarDelegate {

var feedItems = [MWFeedItem]()
var sidebar = SideBar()
var savedFeeds = [Feed]()
var feedNames = [String]()

func request(urlString:String?){

    if urlString == nil{

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/Technology")
        let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: url)
        feedParser.delegate = self
        feedParser.parse()
    }else{

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)
        let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: url)
        feedParser.delegate = self
        feedParser.parse()
    }


}

func loadSavedFeeds (){
    savedFeeds = [Feed]()
    feedNames = [String]()

    feedNames.append("Add Feed")

    let moc = SwiftCoreDataHelper.managedObjectContext()

    let results = SwiftCoreDataHelper.fetchEntities(NSStringFromClass(Feed), withPredicate: nil, managedObjectContext: moc)

    if results.count > 0 {
        for feed in results{
            let f = feed as Feed
            savedFeeds.append(f)
            feedNames.append(f.name)
        }
    }

    sidebar = SideBar(sourceView: self.navigationController!.view, menuItems: feedNames)
    sidebar.delegate = self

}


// MARK: - FEED PARSER DELEGATE

func feedParserDidStart(parser: MWFeedParser!) {
    feedItems = [MWFeedItem]()
}

func feedParserDidFinish(parser: MWFeedParser!) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func feedParser(parser: MWFeedParser!, didParseFeedInfo info: MWFeedInfo!) {
    println(info)
    self.title = info.title
}

func feedParser(parser: MWFeedParser!, didParseFeedItem item: MWFeedItem!) {
    feedItems.append(item)
}


// MARK: - SIDEBAR DELEGATE

func sideBarDidSelectMenuButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {
    if index == 0{ // ADD FEED BUTTON
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add new feed", message: "Enter feed name and URL", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField:UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Feed name"
        })

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField:UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Feed URL"
        })

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alertAction:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let textFields = alert.textFields

            let feedNameTextField = textFields?.first as UITextField
            let feedURLTextField = textFields?.last as UITextField

            if feedNameTextField.text != "" && feedURLTextField.text != "" {
                let moc = SwiftCoreDataHelper.managedObjectContext()

                let feed = SwiftCoreDataHelper.insertManagedObject(NSStringFromClass(Feed), managedObjectConect: moc) as Feed

                feed.name = feedNameTextField.text
                feed.url = feedURLTextField.text

                SwiftCoreDataHelper.saveManagedObjectContext(moc)

                self.loadSavedFeeds()
            }
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }else{
        let moc = SwiftCoreDataHelper.managedObjectContext()

        let selectedFeed = moc.existingObjectWithID(savedFeeds[index - 1].objectID, error: nil) as Feed

        request(selectedFeed.url)


    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadSavedFeeds()


}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    request(nil)

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return feedItems.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedTableViewCell

    cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")


    let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem?
    cell.itemAuthorLabel.text = item?.author
    cell.itemTitleLabel.text = item?.title

    if item?.content != nil {

        let htmlContent = item!.content as NSString
        var imageSource = ""

        let rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, htmlContent.length)
        let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: nil, error: nil)

        if htmlContent.length > 0 {
            let match = regex?.firstMatchInString(htmlContent, options: nil, range: rangeOfString)

            if match != nil {
                let imageURL = htmlContent.substringWithRange(match!.rangeAtIndex(2)) as NSString
                println(imageURL)

                if NSString(string: imageURL.lowercaseString).rangeOfString("feedburner").location == NSNotFound {
                    imageSource = imageURL
                }

            }
        }

        if imageSource != "" {
            cell.itemImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageSource), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
        }else{
            cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
        }

    }


    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem

    let webBrowser = KINWebBrowserViewController()
    let url = NSURL(string: item.link)

    webBrowser.loadURL(url)


    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webBrowser, animated: true)


}   
}
```

**FeedTableViewCell.swift**

```
//
//  FeedTableViewCell.swift
//  RSSReader
//
//  Created by Training on 25/12/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Training. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class FeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var itemTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemAuthorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemImageView: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

**Feed.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Feed : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;

@end
```

Eu quero apenas colocar meu xml: http://multpesquisa.com.br/busca/a

Como ficaria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O link que você postou apesar de também ser um XML **não** é um Feed RSS.

Para mostrar ele você deve:

- Baixar o XML
- Parsear o XML e Criar seu Modelo
- Mostrar os dados na tela

Pude perceber que você está usando o `MWFeedParser`. Não será necessário usar ele.

Há diversas formas de fazer esses passos porém as mais **simples** são:

## Baixar o XML

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://multpesquisa.com.br/busca/a")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

    if (error == nil) {
        self.xml = data
    }
    else {
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }

}
task.resume()
```

## Parsear o XML Criar seu Modelo

Usando XMLDictionary isso é tão simples quanto

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(XMLData: self.xml)
//Estou criando meu modelo aqui ....
```

## Mostrar dados na tela

Agora que você tem os dados no seu modelo é muito fácil! Basta mostrar :D

## Mas.. como baixo as imagens?

Da mesma forma que você baixou o XML!

### E como eu mostro, então?

```
let image = UIImage(data: data)
self.imageView.image(image)
```

Comment: e como eu manipulo item por iem?  pq no xml tem Empresa, e abaixo de empresa tem varios itens, nome, subtitulo, icone, link, etc. esse exemplo que vc postou eh para me criar outro projeto do zero? ou usar o mesmo?

Comment: Esse exemplo é para criar o projeto do zero
Vamos supor que você queira acessar o `subtitulo` do terceiro: `self.dictionary["empresa"]?[(3-1)]["subtitulo"]`

Comment: self.xml = data  esse xml vem de onde? da erro nessa linha

Comment: é um property que você cria `var xml : NSData?` por exemplo

Comment: e se eu quiser mostrar todos ? os nomes e subtitulos

Comment: te enviei o projeto por email